# Event based programming in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, server-side, long-polling

I'm trying to implement a test of Server Side Events using PHP and I have found that I am unable to send a message to my clients based solely on the fact that a variable has changed values.

So far, I am using an infinite `while()` loop to check whether the variable HAS NOT changed, but I am not satisfied with this solution because it is constantly iterating and I believe that it will slow my server down when many people use it (also, it may be a vulnerability to DDoS attacks):

```
$countOld = count($dir);
while (count($dir) == $countOld) {
    sleep(2);
}
echo "event: ping\n";
echo 'data: {"refresh": "1"}';
echo "\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Is there any way to do this without an infinite `while()` loop?

Something that would send the SSE WHEN the variable changes?

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: I would consider using pub/sub for when whatever is writing files to that directory is done.  I also wouldn't use PHP for this.  If you use something like Node.js, you have a lot more flexibility for this style of application.

Comment: Afaik with appserver.io you can do event based systems in PHP, but that is not a prevalent solution... I agree with Brad, I would rather code in nodejs if I would want an event based system. At least nodejs has a bigger hype :D I am not sure that appserver is stable enough. PHP daemons had memory leaks and considered unstable, however I am not certain how they behave in current versions of PHP now.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, node is another option. I wanted to see if there was anything in native PHP that'll do this though. Maybe I'll ask another question for node.js if nothing comes up.

Comment: @HelpingHand If you do go the Node.js route, you can get up and running quickly with Socket.IO (provides a nice RPC, with fallbacks for browsers that don't support web sockets).  You don't have to throw away your PHP apps for this... you can use them side by side.

Comment: @Brad Is SSE Websockets?

Comment: @HelpingHand No, that's something else entirely.  Socket.IO is much more compatible.

Comment: @Brad Sorry to keep bugging you... Last question... Does it use HTTP or do I need to open another port with new logs and vulnerabilities? (I've heard that it uses ws:// and is venerable)

Comment: @HelpingHand All web sockets use HTTP, and then upgrade their protocol.  This is encapsulated with HTTP.  Socket.IO doesn't necessarily use web sockets... it has a whole array of transports from web sockets to long-polling JSON.  Not sure what you're thinking about when you say something is vulnerable.  It's impossible to make a blanket statement.

Comment: @Brad You're right... I guess I was just thinking out loud. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @HelpingHand I am faced with a similar problem.I am employing java threads and recursive functions and some event based functions.

Comment: @NotModerator Yeah, it seems that you cannot do event based programming in PHP because it is not a [single-threaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_threading) programming language... As far as I can tell...